# qemu-system-x86_64: Files\qemu\: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists

Tags: qemu

I am working in a OS and I found a [tutorial for that](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial), and I used the [boot sector code of the 1st part](https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/blob/master/01-bootsector-barebones/boot_sect_simple.asm), the part to compile(from the file "boot.asm" to "boot.bin") worked fine, but it gave a [error  trying running it in qemu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98LYg.png).

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the path for `-L` in quotes:

`-L "C:\Program Files\qemu\"`

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: When I tried, it said: ```qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios-256k.bin'```

Comment: Does "C:\Program Files\qemu\" contain a file named 'bios-256k.bin'?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: If this is the only error message from qemu, then it did not found the bios file or the file size is not divisible by 65536 (`bios_size % 65536) != 0`).  If your bios-256k.bin file size meets this criteria, I recommend to use tools like processMonitor from sysinternals to find out where qemu does search bios-256k.bin. Your command line is OK.